# Python Flask. Keep running the code even if the page from browser was closed

Tags: python, session, flask, background, server

Here is my problem. I want to use Flask framework with python in order to make the web page with the form. After user submits it via browser, he is redirected to another page. And after the page was loaded the specific task (piece of code) should be executed even if the user already closed the page. After code executed user gets email.
Why I need this? Because the code will be executing for long time. In order user doesn't need to wait, I need to solve this problem.
Can you suggest something? May be some other ways (prefferable with Flask)?

Comment: What is "the specific task" that needs to execute— is it server-side python code?

Answer (score 3):

You should run background task after a user submits the form. One possible solution is use something like [Celery](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/celery/).